# Remove 'powered by Google' logo from the autocomplete address search in android

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-places-api

I am developing an app in which i am using a search view to search for the address in autocomplete feature from google places api and selecting one but 'powered by google' logo keeps appearing at the bottom of the autocomplete container and i want it to be removed

Places Autocomplete activity

```
public class Places Autocomplete Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

@BindView(R.id.autocomplete)
PlacesAutocompleteTextView mAutocomplete;

@BindView(R.id.street)
TextView mStreet;

@BindView(R.id.city)
TextView mCity;

@BindView(R.id.state)
TextView mState;

@BindView(R.id.zip)
TextView mZip;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_places_autocomplete);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    mAutocomplete.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new OnPlaceSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(final Place place) {
            mAutocomplete.getDetailsFor(place, new DetailsCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(final PlaceDetails details) {
                    Log.d("test", "details " + details);
                    mStreet.setText(details.name);
                    for (AddressComponent component : details.address_components) {
                        for (AddressComponentType type : component.types) {
                            switch (type) {
                                case STREET_NUMBER:
                                    break;
                                case ROUTE:
                                    break;
                                case NEIGHBORHOOD:
                                    break;
                                case SUBLOCALITY_LEVEL_1:
                                    break;
                                case SUBLOCALITY:
                                    break;
                                case LOCALITY:
                                    mCity.setText(component.long_name);
                                    break;
                                case ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1:
                                    mState.setText(component.short_name);
                                    break;
                                case ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_2:
                                    break;
                                case COUNTRY:
                                    break;
                                case POSTAL_CODE:
                                    mZip.setText(component.long_name);
                                    break;
                                case POLITICAL:
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(final Throwable failure) {
                    Log.d("test", "failure " + failure);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_hide_x) {
        mAutocomplete.showClearButton(false);
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_show_x) {
        mAutocomplete.showClearButton(true);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This is the code for search view activity

Comment: Afaik it's against their policies to remove it.

Comment: Can I can hide it or something ?

Comment: You can if you display a GoogleMap on the same activity that displays "powered by Google": https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/policies#logo_requirements

Comment: Read section 3.2.3 (b) of [Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/), it says: `Attribution.  Customer will display all attribution that (i) Google provides through the Services (including branding, logos, and copyright and trademark notices); or (ii) is specified in the Service Specific Terms. Customer will not modify, obscure, or delete such attribution.`

Comment: Ok, got it, see,i want to retrieve localities and sub-localities of a country, that's why i am using places api in a search activity so that user can search for localities. Is there any other way to retrieve list of localities of a country?

Comment: What's wrong with Google places? You're using their services and not yours so you have to pl by their terms. If you want something else try HERE, but it's not free. Prices range from 0 to $499 per month depending on your calls to their API. Do you really want to pay $499 per month to get rid of a water mark